# how to find the previous clicked class / element - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I have something like a simple color picker.
There is a `select` element to choose 1-3 colors wanted.
after choosing, there will be 1-3 `div` depending on the value selected.
now those `div` has class like `color1`, `color2`, `color3`
Either one clicked, there's another div, `pickcolor` toggled having 8 colors to be chosen.

So right now let's say I click on the `color1` div the `pickcolor` div will pop up and after chosen one of those 8 colors in the `pickcolor` it'll pass the color back to `color1` to show the users.

I can get one done but that's only done by giving static class but when there are two colors or three.  I can't seem to figure out how to use jquery to figure out how to get back to the previous clicked class /element

I have something like this in my html for the select section

```
<select name="number-of-colors" class="number-of-colors">
    <option value="" group="1">Select A Number</option>
    <option value="1" group="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" group="1">2</option>
    <option value="3" group="1">3</option>
</select>
<div class="number-of-color-field">
    <div name="color1" class="color1" id="color1"></div>
    <div name="color2" class="color2"></div>
    <div name="color3" class="color3"></div>
</div>
```

in my jquery I have something like this

```
  $('.number-of-colors').on('change', function(){
    var $clicked = $(this);
    var $closestDiv = $clicked.closest("div");

    var chooseColorValue = $clicked.val();

    if(chooseColorValue == 1){
        $closestDiv.find('div.color1').show().css({"width": "inherit", "height": "100%", "background-color": "pink", "border": "1px solid lightgrey", "border-radius": "5px"});
        $closestDiv.find('div.color2').hide();
        $closestDiv.find('div.color3').hide();

    }else if(chooseColorValue == 2){
        $closestDiv.find('div.color1').show().css({"width": "inherit", "height": "50%", "background-color": "pink", "border": "1px solid lightgrey", "border-radius": "5px"});
        $closestDiv.find('div.color2').show().css({"width": "inherit", "height": "50%", "background-color": "pink", "border": "1px solid lightgrey", "border-radius": "5px"});
        $closestDiv.find('div.color3').hide();

        $closestDiv.find('div.color1').on('click', function(){
            $('.colorSelectBox').css({"left": "100px","top": "570px"}).toggle();
            $('div.black')
                .add('div.pink')
                .add('div.yellow')
                .on('click', function(){
                    var attrValue = $(this).attr('value');
                    $closestDiv.find('div.color1').css({"background-color": attrValue});
                });
        });

        $closestDiv.find('div.color2').on('click', function(){
            $('.colorSelectBox').css({"left": "100px","top": "570px"}).toggle();
            $('div.black')
                .add('div.pink')
                .add('div.yellow')
                .on('click', function(){
                    var attrValue = $(this).attr('value');
                    $closestDiv.find('div.color2').css({"background-color": attrValue});
                });
        });




    }else if(chooseColorValue == 3){
        $closestDiv.find('div.color1').show().css({"width": "inherit", "height": "33%", "background-color": "pink", "border": "1px solid lightgrey", "border-radius": "5px"});
        $closestDiv.find('div.color2').show().css({"width": "inherit", "height": "33%", "background-color": "pink", "border": "1px solid lightgrey", "border-radius": "5px"});
        $closestDiv.find('div.color3').show().css({"width": "inherit", "height": "33%", "background-color": "pink", "border": "1px solid lightgrey", "border-radius": "5px"});
    }else{
        $closestDiv.find('div.color1').hide();
        $closestDiv.find('div.color2').hide();
        $closestDiv.find('div.color3').hide();
    }
});
```

as shown, this will only work for color1 if I duplicate this and use `div.color2` it wouldn't work because it doesn't know where to go.

my color picker div

```
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="colorSelectBox">
                <div>Transparent</div>
                <div>
                    <div class="pink" value="pink"></div>
                    <div class="black" value="black"></div>
                    <div class="yellow" value="yellow"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div>solid</div>
                <div>
                    <div class="red"></div>
                    <div class="blue"></div>
                    <div class="grey"></div>
                    <div class="green"></div>
                    <div class="white"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Please post the full javascript.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki oops, just did...thanks

Comment: Ok thanks @Tsuna, but where's the `pickcolor` div ??

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki added :D thx thx

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is close to what you're looking for. You have to realise that there are **three** parts to your question:

1. Listening to the change event on the `<select>` element, so you can decide how many colours (c1, c2...) the users will be presented with.
2. Show the number of colours. Bind click event to each of these colour fields, which will bring up a palette selector.
3. Bind click event to palette selector, which will assign a colour back to the colour field which triggered it.

The HTML markup is *extremely* minimal because all elements are generated on the fly. Since most of the DOM elements are not present at runtime, you will need to use event delegation (i.e. `.on()`). The palette is defined by the `colors` array of object, which you can of course freely manipulate. I only added 3 colours as a reference.

Without further ado, here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.number-of-colors').on('change', function(){
    // How many colours do the user want? Convert that to an integer
    var colorCount = parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').val(), 10);

    // Empty fields
    $('div.number-of-color-field').empty();

    // Create new fields
    for(var i = 0; i < colorCount; i++) {
      $('<div />', {
        'class': 'color-field-' + (i+1)
      })
      .text('Color field #' + (i+1))
      .appendTo('div.number-of-color-field');
    };
  });

  // Bind click events to color fields
  var colors = [
    { 'class': 'palette-color', 'bgCol': '#d53e4f' },
    { 'class': 'palette-color', 'bgCol': '#f46d43' },
    { 'class': 'palette-color', 'bgCol': '#fdae61' },
    { 'class': 'palette-color', 'bgCol': '#fee08b' },
    { 'class': 'palette-color', 'bgCol': '#e6f598' },
    { 'class': 'palette-color', 'bgCol': '#abdda4' },
    { 'class': 'palette-color', 'bgCol': '#66c2a5' },
    { 'class': 'palette-color', 'bgCol': '#3288bd' }
  ];

  // Bind click event to each color field
  $(document).on('click', 'div.number-of-color-field > div', function() {   
    // Store this reference 
    var that = this;

    // Empty palette
    $('div.color-select-box').empty();

    // Loop through each color
    $.each(colors, function(i, col) {
      $('<div />', {
        'class': col.class
      })
      .css('background-color', col.bgCol)
      .attr({
        'data-bgCol': col.bgCol,
        'data-target': $(that).attr('class')
      })
      .appendTo($('div.color-select-box'));
    });
  });

  // Bind click event to each color box
  $(document).on('click', 'div.color-select-box > div', function() {
    // Empty parent
    $(this).parent().empty();

    // Assign colour to color field
    $('div.number-of-color-field > div.' + $(this).attr('data-target')).css('background-color', $(this).attr('data-bgCol'));
  });
});
```

```css
div.number-of-color-field > div {
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.color-select-box > div {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="number-of-colors" class="number-of-colors">
    <option value="" >Select A Number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div class="number-of-color-field"></div>
<div class="color-select-box"></div>
```

Comment: @_@ so much to in-take.  Is there a way to modify what I already have?

Comment: @Tsuna I don't understand your markup—what is the solid vs transparent fields? What do the colours represent? Then again, you can simply put those colours you want into the `colors` object and you'll see how it works. Also, the answer was published before you provided any markup of sort.

Comment: the semi I believe just color with opacity.
ah, sorry for posting so less earlier. Your way of doing seems so pro to me trying to see if I can get the info from yours and modify mine to get it working before I really try copy and pasting your codes :D

Comment: @Tsuna Did you even try the demo?

Comment: ya I ran your demo snippet it's totally awesome!

Comment: what happens if I have like 4 of the `select` fields? each `select` can choose up to 3 color values

Comment: It's gonna be more complicated, but not too much. You will have to select the colour fields and palette based on context, like `.next()`, so you know which elements should follow the change in the select field value.

Comment: is it possible to use `$(this)`?

Comment: It does not make sense using it unless you're using it within an event handler or an each loop, which will be a reference to the element triggering it.